# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when readind map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a map in java script I am trying to get in  else block   and I get below error.
I am not able to understand and debug this properly.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
fruits : apple,orange,pineapple
countries:usa,uk,india,australia
cities:frankfurt,berlin,moscow

var map ={}; 

map['fruits'] = myObj1;
map['countries'] = myObj2;
map['cities'] = myObj2;

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}

if{

//dosomething

}

else{
var test2=map.get('fruits');

}
```

Comment: could you give some feedback, maybe need another solution..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var test2 = get('fruits');
```

because **map** does not have method **get**,

or change **map** object

```
var map = { get: function (key) { return this[key] }};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get` function isn't a member of `map`, so calling `map.get('fruits')` doesn't work. Either just call `get('fruits')` by itself, or make `get` a member of `map`:

```
map.get = function(k) {
    return this[k];
}
```